# How to read JSON data in RestWebservice from AJAX request

Tags: java, json, ajax, rest

I am trying to send a JSON string from a HTML page using AJAX call to a RESTWebservice. The methods in the server gets invoked however I am not able to retrieve the JSON data that I have set in the browser through AJAX call. I am usng jersy for the REST services.

Here is my HTML code.

```html
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var userConfig = {};
userConfig.user = "arin_12";
userConfig.fullName = "Arindam";
var data = JSON.stringify(userConfig);
alert(data);
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/LiveHive2/rest/hello', true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
        if(req.responseText) {
          alert('The saving of data is ' + req.responseText);
        }
    }
}
req.send(data);
</script>
index page
</body>
```

Here is my JavaCode in RestWebservice.

```
  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String sayJSONHello2(UserConfig uc) {

    System.out.println("req" + uc);  
    return "{\"Name\":\"Arindam\"}";
  }
```

Web.xml looks like this.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the body of the `POST` request will be

```
{
    "user": "arin_12",
    "fullName": "Arindam"
}
```

Write a Java class this JSON can be mappend to.

```
public class UserConfig {
    private String user;
    private String fullName;
    // Constructor, Getter, Setter, ...
}
```

Then JAX-RS allows you to automatically convert the JSON to a class instance.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sayJSONHello2(UserConfig userConfig) {
  System.out.println("got UserConfig: " + userConfig);  
  return "{\"Name\":\"Arindam\"}";
}
```

It is also possible to let JAX-RS handle the mapping of a result to JSON. Let's write a second class for the response.

```
public class HelloResponse {
    private String name;
    // Constructor, Getter, Setter, ...
}
```

Change your JAX-RS method to return an instance of this class.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public HelloResponse sayJSONHello2(UserConfig userConfig) {
  System.out.println("got UserConfig: " + userConfig);  
  return new HelloResponse(userConfig.getName());
}
```

Comment: I tried as suggested. But didn't worked. Now even the sayJSONHello2 method is not getting called. See the new code. Also updated the web.xml.

Comment: Still no progress seems to be there is some major upgrade on JAX-RS2.0. Not able to find any suitable example at all. Hope to get answer from some techie...